# Pandas For Loop Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, optimization

I'm new to python and although I can write for loops with no issue, I'm finding they're horrendously slow. Here's my code:

`perc_match` is a function that runs a calculation between two vectors, which in this case are rows of a dataframe.

```
def perc_match(customer_id,bait_name):
    score = int(df_master.loc[customer_id,:].dot(df_pim.loc[bait_name,:].values))
    perfect = int(df_master.loc[customer_id,:].dot(df_perf.iloc[0,:].values))
    if perfect == 0:
        return 0
    elif (score / perfect)*100 < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        percent = round((score / perfect)*100,3)
        percent = float(percent)
    return percent
```

`match_maker` calls `perc_match` for every row in two dataframes and places the output in its respective cell in `df_match`.

```
def match_maker(df_match):
    for i in df_match.index:
        for j in df_match.columns:
             df_match.loc[i,j] = perc_match(i,j)
```

for reference:

`df_master.shape = (122905, 33)
 df_pim.shape = (36, 33)
 df_perf.shape = (1, 33)
 df_match.shape = (122905, 36)`

This all works fine - except when I test how long it takes...

```
5.49 s ± 72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Not good when I'm running this on 100,000s of rows. I know there are ways to optimize the code, but I'm having a hard time understanding it. What's the best way I can slim this code down?

EDIT:

The inputs look something like this:

`df_master`:

```
 Customer ID       Email       Technique 1       ...        Technique 33
 12345             i@me.com    1                 ...        0
 ...
```

`df_pim`:

```
 Product ID        Technique 1        ...        Technique 33
 Product 1         1                             0
 ...
```

`df_perc` (all values are 1):

```
 index             Technique 1        ...        Technique 33
                   1                             1
```

`df_match`:

```
 Customer ID       Email       Product 1         ...        Product N
 12345             i@me.com    0                 ...        0
 ...
```

I want the function to edit `df_match` to look like this:

`df_match` (gives a % match based on comparison between technique values):

```
 Customer ID       Email       Product 1         ...        Product N
 12345             i@me.com    12.842            ...        44.312
 ...
```

Comment: This seems to be easily vectorizable. Can you post a small example of input and expected output? [refer: [mcve])

Comment: Currently you treat DataFrame just as a multidimensional array with random access. That is not how pandas and other data science packages are typically used. Also as you've discovered, it is terribly slow. Instead, people usually formalize their problems and try to express their solutions as a sequence of predefined array operations. For that you should know what operations exist (see pandas docs).  At very least you should apply your custom function via functional primitives like map, reduce etc. There is no point of optimizing loops & indexing, you should rethink your approach completely.

Comment: Added the input and expected output examples

Comment: This should be a simple problem to vectorize (which will drastically improve performance), however you should post a minimal and reproducible set of example dataframes so that those attempting to answer can replicate your case. Just include a small subset of your data that demonstrates the functionality you are going for.

Comment: From data examples, if I understood correctly, it looks like you have a database-like problem. If you are familiar with relational databases and SQL, you can try to formulate the solution in terms of joins and aggregation with a custom functor. Pandas have relevant functions for that: [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging), [2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). It should be super short and blazing fast comparing to your initial loops.

Comment: Note, that if data comes from an actual DB, you may want to do the transformations in SQL or ORM instead, and only then pass the result to pandas for exploration and processing.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: 
I'm assuming df_perf in perc_match() line 3 is a typo and you meant df_perc.

You are wanting to think of things as individual values to be calculated.  The .dot operator you are using can handle 2 dimensions as well as single dimensions.

In your perc_match() you have:

```
score = int(df_master.loc[customer_id,:].dot(df_pim.loc[bait_name,:].values))
```

this operates on one line at a time times one other line.  How about making a score dataframe with:

```
columns = ["Technique "+str(a) for a in range(1,34)]
score_df = df_master[columns].dot(df_pim)
```

The perfect line is mostly unnecessary if you are multiplying them by a dataframe with all ones.  So how about something like this:

```
perfect = int(df_master.sum(axis=0))
```

This will give you some thoughts to ponder for a while.  I'll finish this answer later or someone can pick this up while I'm away.